# something is wrong in the function which gives wrong alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code which works well and when i do change the dates of enddate to smaller, it keeps on repeating the same alert, i tried the debugging but it is still doing the same thing

here is my code

```
var getMaxApplied = $("##mainform1").find('option:selected').attr('data-maxed');
var capLimit = $("##mainform1").find('option:selected').attr('data-cap');
var appliedLeaves = $("##mainform1").find("##TotalDays_id").val();
alert(appliedLeaves);
alert(getMaxApplied);
alert(capLimit);
if(getMaxApplied != 0.00 && (appliedLeaves < getMaxApplied && capLimit == "N")) {
    ok = true; 
}
if(getMaxApplied != 0.00 && (appliedLeaves > getMaxApplied && capLimit == "Y")) {
    alert('The requested leaves are greather than the cap limit.');
    ok = false; 
}
return ok;
}
```

so if data-maxed is: `11.00`
data-cap is `Y`
and applied leaves can be 30 or 8, if so its 8, it will pass and if its more than 11, it will atop at the alert, so when i play with it, it once shows that alert, i again change the enddate to show only 5 days but i keeps on getting the same alert back to back and it never leaves that section, what is wrong happening here

Comment: What is with the `##` in your ID selectors, `#` is not a valid char in a id attribute value

Comment: What exactly does the "mainform1" element look like in your HTML?

Comment: `appliedLeaves` and `getMaxApplied` are strings. So when you compare them, it performs lexicographic comparison, not numeric, and `"30" < "9"`. Convert them to numbers first.

Comment: mainform1 is a form, ignore the ##, it should be #

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values are **strings**.

When you compare strings with `>` and `<` it is done lexically (i.e. alphabetically, *character-by-character*). `"11"` is less than `"8"` because `"1"` is before `"8"`.

Convert them to numbers (e.g. with the [plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus)) before assigning them to the variables one lines one to three.

Comment: how using plus operator, i think i am missing what you are saying when to convert them to numbers?

Comment: @Dunn — `const a_number = +a_string;`

Comment: thanks, but does it cover a scenario where the value of max aplied is 0.50 or 1.50?

Comment: please reply if u know the answer